# GitHub action artifact not available after downloading

Tags: github-actions

I have a odd problem with github actions where i am downloading and artifact but then

when downloading i get the response

```
Artifact _site was downloaded to /home/runner/work/Singleton/Singleton

Artifact download has finished successfully
```

but then in the next step when trying to push _site to gh-pages it appears that the _site location does not exist

```
 [INFO] copy /home/runner/work/Singleton/Singleton/_site to /home/runner/actions_github_pages_1614076277382

  cp: no such file or directory: /home/runner/work/Singleton/Singleton/_site/*

  cp: no such file or directory: /home/runner/work/Singleton/Singleton/_site/.*
```

is there a step i am missing to make the _site artifact published in a earlier stage accessible?

Comment: Could you share your Workflow Code?

Comment: [link](https://gist.github.com/Reddevildragg/495db0468285853b4b26a8460dec1613) this is the workflow i am using. For a test i removed the deploy job and just put the publish gh-pages step in the build system and it worked, would be good to separate the steps, but at least i got a version running.

Comment: The downloaded artifact is only available to the current job - if that is what you mean :) You have to use download-artifact for every job using the artifact, sadly.

Comment: I believe I am redownloading it on lines 54-58 so that should be available for the next step in that job right?

Comment: Yea - if I understood correctly, this is the version running - correct?

Comment: So this is the version that is not running, it looks like it downloads the artifact but then the deploy step fails cause the artifact does not exist. To get it working i move the deploy step into the build job like this [link](https://github.com/Greener-Games/Singleton/blob/master/.github/workflows/main.yml)

Comment: Hm, was sadly not able to re-build the project - guess there is some kind of license missing. Anways: What I would have done is:
1) Explicit path for download-action (path: _site)
2) Check what happens with a:
run: ls -al && ls -al _site

Comment: It looks like declaring a location for the download-action appears to have fixed the issue. Guessing it was not quite downloading the artifact fully where i though/under the name i thought. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ThomasGreener, location?  Do you mean path?

I'm specifying a path and it stlll isn't working:

https://github.com/Sauceforge/Saucery/blob/feature/multi-stage/.github/workflows/pipeline.yml

https://github.com/Sauceforge/Saucery/actions/runs/7135430875/job/19432176778